# Drupal 8 Views exposed filters > Taxonomy terms with checkboxes and automatic view update

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am looking for a way to have an exposed filter consisting of taxonomy terms which can be selected by means of checkboxes.
Preferably with the possibility of multiple selections, but not necessarily, automatic update of the view after selection (ajax) is another wish.
I tried the module 'Better exposed filters', but this only seems to work on select lists.
Anyone aware of a method do accomplish this with taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0):

This has been [answered on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-01-15/views-exposed-filters-taxonomy-terms-with-checkboxes-and#comment-12964761) by [Bluelake](https://www.drupal.org/u/bluelake)

> First you need to enable the "allow multiple selections" option for your filter itself. Next you have to go to the settings in better exposed filters and select Checkboxes/Radio buttons option under the "display exposed filter as" option. This will display your (taxonomy terms) filters as checkboxes.
>
> For automatic update of the view after filter selection, you must first enable AJAX for the view, then you have to go to better exposed filters options and enable the "Autosubmit" option. Now you have checkbox filters which update the view automatically using AJAX.